# Vuetify async search is only submitting one character at a time and doesn't concat characters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have the following vue component:

```
<template>
    <v-form ref="form" @submit.prevent="search">
        <v-row class="pa-0">
            <v-col cols="12" md="2" class="d-flex">
                <v-autocomplete
                    :items="projects"
                    item-value="id"
                    :item-text="item =>  `${item.number.number} ${item.name}`"
                    outlined
                    v-model="form.project_id"
                    label="Project number"
                    :search-input.sync="project"
                    dense
                    hide-details="auto"
                    class="align-self-center"
                    clearable
                />
            </v-col>
         </v-row>
       </v-form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   watch: {
      project( value )
            {
                this.queryProjects( { search: '', number: value } );
            }
   },

   data()
   {
        return {
            project: '',
            projects: [],
            }
        },

     methods: {
            async queryProjects( search )
            {
                console.log(search);
                if(!search)
                {
                    return;
                }

                let response = await fetch(route('projects.search', search));
                this.projects = await response.json();
            },
    }
}
</script>
```

This component should filter projects based on project number. The `queryProject` function is triggered but the problem is in the `value` from the `project` watcher. After each number entered the autocomplete field is set back to `null` and so it doesn't concat the complete project number. So if you would like to search for `19320` each number is parsed one by one and not as a whole number.

When a character is typed the output in console is the following:

- `1` for watcher value
- `{number: "1"}` for `queryProject` `search` value
- `null` for watcher value so looks like each character resets the input or rerenders the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the line

```
:item-text="item =>  `${item.number.number} ${item.name}`"
```

When changed to just `item-text="name"` everything was working again.

A related bug report: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11370